# save dynamically created controls data in database asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating controls using viewbag that has a list of item

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var savedAdditionalFields = afs.getAllStudentFieldss(1);
            ViewBag.AdditionalFieldList = savedAdditionalFields;
            return View();
        }
```

In the view i am using

### Create

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>StudentAdditionalDetail</legend>

    @foreach (MyClass item in ViewBag.AdditionalFieldList)
        { 

        <div>

            @Html.DisplayFor(itemlist=>item.Name)

            @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.AdditionalInfo)

        </div>
        }
```

The controls and labels are created. 
Now i am saving the items in database using

```
[HttpPost]

 public ActionResult Create(StudentAdditionalDetail additionalFields)

        {   
            ads.AddAdditionalDetails(additionalFields);//calls the insert method

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

But only the first Textbox's data is getting saved in database.I think i need to iterate my [HttpPost] Create Method.But not sure where should i put the code that will iterate throughout my Create View and all the items in

> model.AdditionalInfo

will be saved into database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(List<StudentAdditionalDetail> additionalFields)
{
      ads.AddAdditionalDetails(additionalFields);//calls the insert method
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```